# How can we change the width/padding of a Flutter DropdownMenuItem in a Dropdown?

Tags: padding, dropdown, flutter

In Flutter, I can build a Dropdown with DropdownMenuItems, like this:
[image]

The DropdownMenuItems I add are always wider than the dropdown itself:

[image]

How do you adjust the width of the DropdownMenuItem, or remove the extra horizontal padding?

My DropdownMenuItem widget looks like this:

```
DropdownMenuItem(
    value: unit.name,
    child: Text('hey'),
);
```

while my Dropdown widget looks like this:

```
return Container(
    width: 300.0,
    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton(
        value: name,
        items: listOfDropdownMenuItems,
        onChanged: onChanged,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
      ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

This feature has been added. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/14849

You can now wrap it in a ButtonTheme and set `alignedDropdown` to true.

```
return Container(
    width: 300.0,
    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: ButtonTheme(
        alignedDropdown: true,
          child: DropdownButton(
            value: name,
            items: listOfDropdownMenuItems,
            onChanged: onChanged,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
         ),
      ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Is it possible to set height of DropDown Button.

Comment: @ShangariC yes, I think you can use `padding`.

Comment: now the opened dropdown menu matches the button, in total size, but the text itself don't align, it seem to be the padding in each item that causing problem. how do I remove the padding on individual choices?  if I add it to the item directly it also add padding to selected (button item)

Comment: this proposed solution creates a new problem where the dropdown label text is no longer aligned as it is now indented

Answer (score 38):

I solved this problem with changing `isExpanded` to true;

```
return Container(
    width: 300.0,
    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton(
        isExpanded: true,
        value: name,
        items: listOfDropdownMenuItems,
        onChanged: onChanged,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
      ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Didn't help me.

Comment: What about padding?

Comment: showing error in console - Unfortunately, this object's geometry is not known at this time, probably because it has never been laid out. This means it cannot be accurately hit-tested.
E/flutter (22476): If you are trying to perform a hit test during the layout phase itself, make sure you only hit test nodes that have completed layout (e.g. the node's children, after their layout() method has been called).

Answer (score 10):

`isExpanded: true` will stretch the width to full screen. But if you want a customise drop-down. Here is my customdropdown.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class CustomDropDown extends StatelessWidget {
  final value;
  final List<String> itemsList;
  final Color dropdownColor;
  final Function(dynamic value) onChanged;
  const CustomDropDown({
    @required this.value,
    @required this.itemsList,
    this.dropdownColor,
    @required this.onChanged,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 3, bottom: 3, right: 20),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0, right: 14),
            child: DropdownButton(
              isExpanded: true,
              dropdownColor: dropdownColor,
              value: value,
              items: itemsList
                  .map((String item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: item,
                        child: Text(item),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
              onChanged: (value) => onChanged(value),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can call it like this.

```
CustomDropDown(
   value: selectedValue,
   itemsList: ['Music', 'Photographer'],
   onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
            selectedValue = value;
        });
    },
),
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case this is working.

```
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: ContactColors.hint2, width: 2)),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                      hint: new Text("Select City"),
                      isExpanded: true,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      value: dropdownValue,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                      elevation: 16,
                      style: const TextStyle(color: ContactColors.white),
                      onChanged: (String? value) {
                        // This is called when the user selects an item.
                        setState(() {
                          dropdownValue = value!;
                        });
                      },
                      items: list
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: Text(value,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: ContactColors.primaryColor)),
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    )),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by adding isExpanded: true then wraping dropdown to a container then again wraping to padding widget this worked for me

code : -

```
Container(
                        height: 60,
                        width: double.infinity,
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    border: Border.all(color: borderContainerColor, width: 3)),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), //here include this to get padding
                          child: DropdownButton(

                            isExpanded: true,
                            underline: Container(),

                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,


                            elevation: 0,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5 ),
                            value: dropdownvalue,
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),

                            items: items.map((String items) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem(
                                value: items,
                                child: Text(items),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                            onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                              setState(() {
                                dropdownvalue = newValue!;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Try with this parameter  `isDense`
it will shrink the widget and extra padding will be removed
just like this

```
DropdownButton(
          isDense: true,
          value : lname_listValue,
          items: casteEDList.map((String items)
                   {
                       return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: items,
                              child: Text(items),);
                   }).toList(),
                   onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                              setState(() {
                              lname_listValue = newValue!;
                              },);
                   },
  ),
```

Comment: Didn't do anything